# Chilcot Report did not express a view on whether the invasion was legal. Which forum is responsible for it?

Tags: united-kingdom, law, armed-conflict, war-crime

The [Iraq inquiry](http://edition.cnn.com/2016/07/06/europe/uk-iraq-inquiry-chilcot-report/) finally gave it's report; *Chilcot Report*. While the legal basis for the war was "far from satisfactory," the inquiry did not express a view on whether the invasion was legal, Chilcot said, arguing that was a decision for another forum.

> Which forum is responsible for it?

Answer (score 4):

In a state where [rule of law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_law) prevails, the only forum which has the authority to judge if a certain action was legal or illegal is a criminal court.